# PHP Switch isn't working

Tags: php

I have this switch

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$type = $_POST['type'];
{
        switch($type)
        {
            case 'm':
                echo "Hello male";
                break;
            case 'f':
                echo "Hello female";
                break;
            case 'c':
                echo "Hello child";
                break;
            default:
                echo "you have to choose";
                break;
        }
}
```

which should work with this form:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<p>
    <input name="type" type="radio" value="f" />Woman
    <br>
    <input name="type" type="radio" value="m" />Male
    <br>
    <input name="type" type="radio" value="c" />Child
    <br>
    <input type="type" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

but when I test it, it returns with undefined variable in all the cases. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

Simple Typo:

Change:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
$type = $_POST['type'];
{
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$type = $_POST['type'];
```

You have misplaced curly brace.

Therefore, the code to be executed after `POST` is getting executed by default.

If you do not place curly brace after any expression eg. `if`, `else`, `while`, `foreach`, only one successive line of code will be executed.

Therefore, its a better practice to add curly braces after these controls even if they contain only one line of code.

Comment: I guess I stared myself a bit blind at this, thank you!

Comment: Now, why does the default return with this error:

"Notice: Undefined index: type in [...]"?

Refering to this line: 

    `$type = $_POST['type'];`

Answer (score 2):

Use this:
**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    $type = $_POST['type'];
      switch($type)
        {
            case 'm':
                echo "Hello male";
                break;
            case 'f':
                echo "Hello female";
                break;
            case 'c':
                echo "Hello child";
                break;
            default:
                echo "you have to choose";
                break;
        }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<p>
    <input name="type" type="radio" value="f" />Woman
    <br>
    <input name="type" type="radio" value="m" />Male
    <br>
    <input name="type" type="radio" value="c" />Child
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input type="type" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
             ^^^^^^                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the curley brackets after `$_POST['type'];`

Must be like this:

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
switch($type)
{
    case 'm':
        echo "Hello male";
        break;
    case 'f':
        echo "Hello female";
        break;
    case 'c':
        echo "Hello child";
        break;
    default:
        echo "you have to choose";
        break;
}
```